# Eclipse Juno won't let me install XML Editor

Tags: eclipse

I have Eclipse Juno:

```
Version: 3.7.2
Build id: I20110613-1736
```

I'm trying to install the XML Editors from the Install Software option under Help using this repo:

```
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/
```

And I keep getting dependency problems when installing:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 3.4.2.v201211061806-7H7GFeJDxumUrsn5qkiQgOEhsz0p60HAmPyU6VX (org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group 3.4.2.v201211061806-7H7GFeJDxumUrsn5qkiQgOEhsz0p60HAmPyU6VX)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.I20110613-1736 (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.7.0.I20110613-1736)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Core Resource Management 3.8.0.v20120522-2034 (org.eclipse.core.resources 3.8.0.v20120522-2034)
    Core Resource Management 3.8.1.v20121114-124432 (org.eclipse.core.resources 3.8.1.v20121114-124432)
    Core Resource Management 3.8.1.v20120802-154922 (org.eclipse.core.resources 3.8.1.v20120802-154922)
    Core Resource Management 3.7.101.dist (org.eclipse.core.resources 3.7.101.dist)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.2.dist-9nF7UHagFqn9pElwWhC90gLz-soEuSGYmtSeiRH (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.2.dist-9nF7UHagFqn9pElwWhC90gLz-soEuSGYmtSeiRH)
    To: org.eclipse.core.resources [3.7.101.dist]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.I20110613-1736 (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.7.0.I20110613-1736)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.7.2.dist-9nF7UHagFqn9pElwWhC90gLz-soEuSGYmtSeiRH]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 3.4.2.v201211061806-7H7GFeJDxumUrsn5qkiQgOEhsz0p60HAmPyU6VX (org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group 3.4.2.v201211061806-7H7GFeJDxumUrsn5qkiQgOEhsz0p60HAmPyU6VX)
    To: org.eclipse.wst.xsd.ui [1.2.500.v201203081826]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: XSD Core Plugin 1.1.700.v201204102147 (org.eclipse.wst.xsd.core 1.1.700.v201204102147)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.core.resources [3.8.0,4.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: XML Schema Editor 1.2.500.v201203081826 (org.eclipse.wst.xsd.ui 1.2.500.v201203081826)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.wst.xsd.core [1.1.300,1.2.0)
```

I should mention this is on Ubuntu 12.04 installed from Repos. I have done a fresh install and emptied my Workspace directory after removing. To remove I did a:

```
sudo apt-get remove eclipse-* --purge
```

Then I ran `autoclean` and `clean` along with `deborphan` to remove all package dependencies for Eclipse. Afterwords I re-installed for which it re-downloaded everything.

Still the same dependency problem and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have Juno, that would be [3.8 or 4.2](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Older_Versions_Of_Eclipse). Therefore the update site doesn't match your installation.

On Ubuntu, please do not use the Eclipse versions from the package manager. Instead download them from the website and install them anywhere you like (by means of unzipping). In most Linux distributions, the packaged Eclipse versions are way outdated (as you can see by your build id, dating from June 2011).